# Location of SQLite DB on Android Device?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wrote an Android app and installed it on my Pixel 4a.  The app creates a local SQLite DB that, according to all information I can find, is located in the /data/data directory.  If I look at the directories on my phone using Google's Files app, I don't see a /data directory.  Where is the DB located or how do I get to the /data directory?  I'd like to be able to download the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't access root files using files app without root. use device expoler in andriod studio to access it when in debug mode

Comment: Thanks!  That clears up my confusion.